# How to place widgets in tkinter so that it can work on Windows 10 as it works in Linux?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout, tkinter-menu

I have a lot of items to set in GUI like tables, labels, buttons. The problem is when I use this GUI in Windows 10 everything doesn't appear as it appears in Linux.(e.g., only half of the table is visible)
I don't know what to use so that it can work and everything can appears/works for both OS. I can use pack instead of place but this is very difficult when you have a lot of items. I tried to categorize items and use like 5-6 frames but frames doesn't work because I have an background image.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import BOLD
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk



class MyApp():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.w, self.h = self.window.winfo_screenwidth(), self.window.winfo_screenheight()
        #self.window.geometry("%dx%d" % (self.w, self.h))
        self.window.attributes("-zoomed",True) ## for WINDOWS self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", self.fullScreenState)
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "a.jpg")
        # Show image using label
        label1 = Label(self.window,image=bg)
        label1.place(x=0,y=0,width= self.w, height=self.h)
        self.widgets()
        # Infinite loop can be terminated by keyboard or mouse interrupt
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.exit)
  
        self.window.mainloop()
        

    def exit(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.window.destroy()


            
    def widgets(self):
        
        #style.theme_use('pastel')

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.window, columns=("columns1","columns2","columns3","columns4" ), show="tree",
        selectmode="extended")
        self.tree.place(x=995,y=130,width=863,height=602)
        table_style = ttk.Style()
        table_style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=60,background = "white",fieldbackground = "white",font=('Calibri', 15))
        table_style.configure("Treeview.Heading", foreground='#00337f',background ="#3D98DD")
        self.tree.column("#0", minwidth=0, width=180, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#1", minwidth=0, width=180, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#2", minwidth=0, width=180, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#3", minwidth=0, width=180, stretch=NO)
        self.table_lable = Label(self.window)
        self.table_lable.place(x=996,  y=30)
        for row in range(11):
            self.tree.insert("", END, values="",text="ROW %d"%row)
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values="", tag='gray',text="")
        self.tree.tag_configure('gray', background='#cccccc')

        self.panel = Label(self.window,borderwidth=10, relief="groove")
        self.panel.place(x=20, y=130,width=560,height=500)

        self.panel2 = Label(self.window,borderwidth=10, relief="groove")
        self.panel2.place(x=640, y=130,width=300,height=500)

        self.max_prog_nr = 0
        self.style = ttk.Style(self.window)
        self.style.layout('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
                    [('Horizontal.Progressbar.trough',
                    {'children': [('Horizontal.Progressbar.pbar',
                                    {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'})],
                        'sticky': 'nswe'}),
                    ('Horizontal.Progressbar.label', {'sticky': ''})])
                    # , lightcolor=None, bordercolo=None, darkcolor=None
        self.style.configure('text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', text='0 %')
        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.window, style='text.Horizontal.TProgressbar', length=560,
                                    maximum=self.max_prog_nr, value=0)
        self.progress_bar.place(x=20,  y=60)
        prog_bar_label = Label(self.window)
        prog_bar_label.place(x=20, y=30)
        self.prog_num = 1

window= Tk()
start= MyApp(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot from Winddows and from Linux.

[Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VkA5.png)

[Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xh0b.jpg)

Comment: The GUI should look the same on both Windows and Linux. The only difference should be in the fonts available. Try setting the font and the font size for all of your widgets. Make sure that that font is available on both your OSs.

Comment: Please try to remove all of the unnecessary imports in the example, and try to make an example that doesn't depend on external image files.

Comment: The single best thing you can do is stop using `place`, and instead use `pack` and/or `grid`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Does `place` behave differently on different OSs? I thought that all geometry managers should behave the same way on all OSs.

Comment: No, `place` works exactly the same. However, different platforms have different fonts, different, resolutions, different borderwidth or styles, etc. When you use `place` you have to write extra code to account for all of those differences.

Comment: @BryanOakley, but there is no problem in using `pack` or `grid` in different platforms right?

Comment: `pack`, `place`, and `grid` all perform exactly the same on all platforms. The difference is in the widgets. Different platforms use different fonts, have different screen resolutions, possibly different borderwidths and padding, and so on.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for answering. I removed imports and add some screenshots. Actually I have a lot of imports, this is only a bit from the code I have. There are more buttons, radiobuttons, scales etc. I know that pack is better than place but I have a lot of items so it is very difficult to place them. Is there any other method to handle it?